# How can I remove all records from a table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to delete all records from my SQL Server table. I use LINQ to EF5. Is there anything I can do to do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
context.Entities.DeleteAllOnSubmit(dc.Entities);
```

Comment: Does that DELETE all the rows, or TRUNCATE?